# Mongo. how to check if field is a number

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How to select mongodb documents where field is a number?

Some examples of the content of this field: "2", "a", "Z", 3

Comment: One method is to use `$type`: `db.col.find({Z: {$type:16}})`

Comment: Yes, I've tried it, but I thought there should be another solution.

Comment: Hmm, I was gonna say regex but that can only know if the string/int is a number it cannot know if it is a data type of string or int

Comment: I think, the problem will be way simpler if we consider there field is of length = 1 (or one digit)

Comment: Ok lets break this down, I am confused why $type wont work, maybe I am being dumb; can you give a full example?

Comment: because "4" and 4 are of different type

Comment: But you want them both matched? If so you cold regex it `{field: /^[0-9]+$/}`

Comment: Consider the following improvement of the current answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/67644929/3665178

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can use the [$type](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/type/) operator to select based on the BSON type of the field, which should get you what you want.

So, for example, to find all strings:

```
db.collection.find( { field: { $type : 2 } } )
```

Or, to find all doubles (which is usually what numbers get stored as from the shell thanks to the default Javascript behavior), you would use:

```
db.collection.find( { field: { $type : 1 } } )
```

Since there are two types of integer (potentially) you would need to go with something like this:

```
db.collection.find({$or : [{"field" : { $type : 16 }}, {"field" : { $type : 18 }}]})
```

Finally then, to get all numbers, integer or double:

```
db.collection.find({$or : [{"field" : { $type : 1 }}, {"field" : { $type : 16 }}, {"field" : { $type : 18 }}]})
```

Comment: The $type operator works bad with string representation of number. Any other thoughts? Since I have field with length of 1, probably I can use $in, but it looks a little bit ugly

Comment: If you have string representations of numbers, then they are strings, not numbers.  You could to a regex (expensive) or you could write a function to check, but there's nothing native in the database to do it for you.

Comment: We warned though: BSON type 2 (string) will return truthy for arrays containing strings.

Answer (score 17):

You can the type of a field `bar` by using

```
typeof db.foo.findOne().bar
```

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/shell-types/#check-types-in-shell

Answer (score 12):

you can use the alias "number" instead:

```
{ field: {$type:"number"}}
```

Answer (score 2):

`typeof` in mongo returns `object` for `array` type also. To check if a field is a `Number`, run below query to see if it returns any result.

`db.foo.find('Object.prototype.toString.call(this.bar) === "[object Number]"')`

You can also see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString

Comment: I needed a method of finding records where a certain field was _not_ an integer, and this (with a !== replacing the ===) worked wonderfully; thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The current answer is totally valid

The complete table about the **Type/Number/Alias** is in the [BSON Types](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/)

Now, according with the [$type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) documentation

The current solution

```
db.collection.find({$or : [{"field" : { $type : 1 }}, 
                           {"field" : { $type : 16 }}, 
                           {"field" : { $type : 18 }}]})
```

Can be *improved* (tested by myself) to the following:

```
//based on 'Number' - see BSON Types
db.collection.find({ "field": { $type: [1, 16, 18] } })
```

or

```
//based on 'Alias' BSON Types
db.collection.find({ "field": { $type: ["double", "int", "long"] } })
```

Therefore is possible avoid use `$or` and repeat multiple times the *same* `field` name

Answer (score 0):

With the mongodb **4.4** (upcoming), You can use [**`$isNumber`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/isNumber/) pipeline operator to check whether the expression is integer or other BSON type.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "field": { "$isNumber": "$field" }
  }}
])
```

And to get only the selected documents

```
db.collection.find({ "$expr": { "$anyElementTrue": { "$isNumber": "$field" }}})
```